# Google drive api, upload file with shared permission

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

Im trying to upload file to the google drive, and I want to set 'shared' permission for this file, but I don't know how to do it...
I tried to use this code, but the file is uploaded without the shared permission.

My code is:

```
// _drive - google drive object
Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File item = new Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File();

Permission permission = new Permission();
permission.Role = "reader";
permission.Type = "anyone";
permission.WithLink = true;

item.Permissions = new List<Permission>() { permission };
FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = _drive.Files.Insert(item, fileStream, mimeType);
request.Upload();
```

Comment: Just curious. can you try and do a patch on the permissions after you have uploaded the file and see if that works?   I am wondering if its a bug in the client lib, what you are doing should work.

Comment: Yes, if I change permission after file uploading - its work. But in this case i spend one excess drive quota...

Comment: Its probably a bug in the client lib.   try adding a issue https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/list  I will test it when I get home.  but like I said your code looks correct.

Comment: Ok, I will wait for your test, and if it's a really bug - please add issue by yourself, because my english is bad :)

Answer (score 2):

OK I have spent the last hour playing around with this.  If you check out [Files.insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert) documentation it doesn't really state anyplace that you should be able to set the permissions at insert time.

At the bottom if you test out **try it**. Setting the permissions up as you have done above under `Request body`.

[image]

It does upload the file.  But the Json returned gives us a clue.

```
"shared": false,
```

Now if i check the file in Google drive

[image]

This leads me to believe that this is not supported by the Google Drive API. It is **not** possible to set the permissions at the time of upload. You are going to have to create a separate call to set the permissions after you have uploaded the file.

While it looks like the body does support the permissions it doesn't appear to be working.  I am not sure if this is a bug or something that is just not supported.  I am going to see if i can find the location of the issue tracker for Drive and add it as an issue.

In the mean time you are going to have to make the two calls and eat a bit of your Quota.

[Issue 3717:    Google drive api, upload file with shared permission](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3717)

Answer (score 1):

Also experienced this bug. Specifying permissions in the same file / directory upload, had to do it in a separate request, like below. The Google Drive API documentation is not clear about this (and not clear about how to handle file permissions when using a Service Account).

```
var NewDirRequest = DService.Files.Insert(GoogleDir);
var NewDir = NewDirRequest.Execute();
GoogleFolderID = NewDir.Id;

var NewPermissionsRequest = DService.Permissions.Insert(new Permission()
{
    Kind = "drive#permission",
    Value = emailAddress,
    Role = "writer",
    Type = "user"
}, GoogleFolderID);

DService.Permissions.Insert(new Permission()
{
    Kind = "drive#permission",
    Value = "mydomain.com",
    Role = "reader",
    Type = "domain"
}, GoogleFolderID);

NewPermissionsRequest.Execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for a simple `Python` solution here as me:

```
# upload file to drive
uploaded_file = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media, fields='id').execute()

# set permission - toAll - for file in drive
drive_service.permissions().create(fileId=uploaded_file['id'], body={'role': 'reader', 'type': 'anyone'}).execute()
```